# FTP-клиент на Node.js для Windows Server

Tags: linux, node.js, windows-server

### Имеется

- Дистрибутив Linux (Debian) с установленной платформой Node.js
- Сторонний Windows Server

### Задача

Необходимо установить FTP коннект к Windows Server при помощи платформы Node.js, вырезать определенную папку (вместе с находящимися в ней папками и файлами) и вставить в определенную директорию на сервере под управлением Linux.

### Вопрос

Можно ли реализовать описанную задачу? Если "Да", то какие NPM-пакеты использовать и/или какой код программы подойдет для решения задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ходить по обычному FTP, то инструкция получилась такая:

1. Добавить службу FTP-сервер (веб-сервер IIS)
2. Добавить FTP-сайт и установить физический путь к каталогу с содержимым

При помощи NPM-пакета **basic-ftp**, получить содержимое каталога:

```
const ftp = require('basic-ftp');

ftp_connect()
 
async function ftp_connect() {
    const client = new ftp.Client();
    client.ftp.verbose = true;
    try {
        await client.access({
            host: 'host',
            port: '21',
            user: 'domain\\username',
            password: 'password',
            secure: false
        })
        console.log(await client.list())
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    client.close()
}
```